# Most efficient way to compare a list of strings to a list of objects with a string field

Tags: java, list

So I have this problem that actually occurs a lot in my code but here's the easiest example of it. The problem is I have an object which contains a list of Strings which correspond to the 'name' or 'id' or 'username' (it depends) fields of another object. So, for example, I have a `PublishGroupType` object which looks like this:

```
public class PublishGroupType {
    protected List<String> username;
    protected String name;
    public List<String> getUsername() {
        if (username == null) {
            username = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        return this.username;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String value) {
        this.name = value;
    }
    //etc...
}
```

and a `UserModel` object that looks like this:

```
public class UserModel {
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
        userData.put(UserColumns.USERNAME.getUserColumnName(), username);
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
        userData.put(UserColumns.PASSWORD.getUserColumnName(), password);
    }
    //etc
}
```

Now because of other reasons I am not allowed to make major changes to `PublishGroupType` so I cannot directly change the list to contain a list of `UserModel`s instead of `String`s. But, I can add a `Group` field to `UserModel` and I can create a wrapper class `GroupModel` which looks like this:

```
public class GroupModel{

    public PublishGroupType publishGroupType;
    public List<UserModel> users;

    public GroupModel(PublishGroupType publishGroup) {
        this.publishGroupType = publishGroup;

        List<UserModel> allUsers = userManagementClient.getAllUsers();

        //populate the users here from a list of all users 
        for(UserModel user : userManagementClient.getAllUsers()){
            if(publishGroupType.getUsername().contains(user.getUsername())){
                users.add(user);
                user.setGroup(this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is there are many times more users in the list of all users than there are in a Group, so this is really inefficient to loop through all users for each group. Keep in mind that this is one small and simple example of a problem that happens A LOT all over my code base. Is there a better way to match `UserModel`s with their string `Username`s?

Comment: Instead of having a all-users list, you should probably have a map. Or better yet, a database.

Comment: Can't you obtain a UserModel from userManagementClient.get(username) in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'm a little confused as to whether your question is generic like the title of your post:

> compare a list of strings to a list of objects with a string field

or if it's specific like the last line in your post:

> Is there a better way to match UserModels with their string Usernames?

I'm going to answer the latter.

Here's what I would suggest - have the `userManagementClient` maintain a `HashMap` whose keys are the usernames and whose values are the `UserModel` objects.  Then you can modify the class (not sure of the name, you didn't provide it) whose instance you called `userManagementClient` to provide a method to get the `UserModel` based on a `String` parameter (the username):

```
public UserModel getUserModel(String username){
    return userMap.get(username);
}
```

Then you can change your loop from this:

```
for(UserModel user : userManagementClient.getAllUsers()){
    if(publishGroupType.getUsername().contains(user.getUsername())){
        users.add(user);
        user.setGroup(this);
    }
}
```

to this:

```
for(String user : publishGroupType.getUsername()){
    UserModel userModel = userManagementClient.getUserModel(user);
    if(userModel != null){
        users.add(user);
        user.setGroup(this);
    }else{
       //handle missing user appropriately
    }
}
```

Now you're only looping through the users associated with the `publishGroupType` instead of all the users and you're able to obtain the `UserModel` without using `contains` over and over.

One final thought - this question probably would have been a better fit for [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) since the code works without errors.